# Convert dateformat or obtain dateformat from date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, underscore.js, momentjs

I have a dateformat like this one "%d-%m-%Y" and I need to pass this format to Datepicker, but the Datepicker does not allow this format as far as I'm aware. Since this format is introduced by the user, I can not predict wich format will be introduced.

I only have momentjs, jquery, underscore and datepicker to handle this because the system I'm working is quite restrictive (they do not allow me to install new plugins)

MomentJS returns a Date Object, and it does not convert the format string inside it, so I can't retrieve it or extract it to use it in the datepicker dateformat.

Is there a way to pass this unix format to datepicker, or to convert similar strings like this one "%d-%m-%Y" to "dd-mm-YY"

The order could be anything from this "%Y-%m-%d" or just one part of it "%Y"

**Edit 1:**

To clarify this better, I need to convert from this string "%d-%m-%Y" to this one "DD-MM-YYYY" but the symbols could be in any order, and there are also other symbols:

%a %A %b %B %c  %d %H %I %j %m %M %p %S %U %W %w %x %X %y %Y %Z %%

Comment: I'm bit lost. You said that you have this format `%d-%m-%Y` but the again you say that you can't predict the format being introduced by the user? Just tell them to put that one. You can easily change `datepicker` format anytime using `altFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'`

Comment: @spokey I provided %d-%m-%Y as an example of the user input in other place of the app, as I said in the last line _The order could be anything from this "%Y-%m-%d" or just one part of it "%Y"_

Comment: Which datepicker are we talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [moment-strftime plugin](https://github.com/benjaminoakes/moment-strftime), which understands tokens in that format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) in MomentJS to get your string back.

```
// will return a string
moment().format('DD-MM-YY');
```

Comment: Not possible, the format that you introduced is a constant; I receive formats similar to this one "%d-%m-%Y"

Comment: So do you need a way to map date formats from what you are receiving to a MomentJS format? If not, since you didn't post any code, it would be great to update your question with a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).